# How to click and drag the google map from the info window like we click and drag the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, draggable

How to click and drag the google map from the info window like we click and drag the map. As I have tried to far, once the info window is opened, I can't drag the map unless I need to click the map to start dragging/pannning.

Is there any solution for this? It is irritated to drag the map if there is a huge info window that is cover on the screen since I want user to read the info window content while able to drag/pan the map even if they click+drag on the info window.

**Failed Solution** I have tried so far is to punch a trigger to the map+drag event, however it doesn't have any effect.

**IMPORTANT:** Even though if there is solution for this, I still be able want to access to the info window content in order to click or copy the info window content.

Need pro's help...

Comment: Have you tried the keyboard arrows?

Comment: Keyboard yes, working. However I need a good UX approach so user can also drag the map through the infowindow.

Comment: You could use mouse button 3 down and `mousemove` to watch `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`...  Then simulate arrows keypress... Have fun ;)

Comment: any other solution? any1?